# On the iPad, how can I make the embedded sound on my web page stop playing when the browser is 'closed'?

Tags: ios, ipad, audio, safari

I have a web page that plays an embedded sound. If I "close" the browser on the iPad while the sound is playing, the sound does not stop. How can I make the sound stop playing when the browser is not visible?

Comment: Did you ever manage to find a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thought I'd let you know, since I just managed to [find a solution.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14438227/401137)

Code like this, should work:

```
var lastSeen;
var loop = function (){
    lastSeen = Date.now();
    setTimeout(loop, 50);
};
loop();

var music = document.getElementById('music');
music.addEventListener('timeupdate', function (){
    if(Date.now() - exports.lastSeen > 100){
        this.pause();
    }
}, false);
```

Comment: Thanks, I think this is similar to the solution we finally went with.